# video player background like jquery lightbox

Tags: php, html, javascript, jquery

I have written some code to display a YouTube video on my page but I want it to be like Lightbox. So I have created the following `div`:

```
<div id="video-background" class="vid_back" ></div>
```

and I have a jQuery function to append YouTube video:

```
 $("#video_one").click(function () {

            $("#video-background").append("<div id=\"video_player_box\"><div id=\"close\" >X</div><iframe title=\"YouTube video player\" class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" " +
            "width=\"640\" height=\"390\" src=\"" + vid_one + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowFullScreen></iframe></div>");

            state = 1;
        });
```

While there is no problem until here, I want to close this thing when they click the "X". To implement this I did:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#close").live("click", function(){ 
      $("#video-background").remove("div"); 

    });
  });
```

While this works, when I click again the link to show the video, nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Comment: In the future, post your programming questions on Stack Overflow, please. You already have an account there. This question will be migrated soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this fiddle helps you out.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwULw/

Comment: Thanks. this one works , too. But i did  $("#video-background").children("div").remove();  instead of  $("#video-background").remove("div");

But your answer also works, thanks.